# ERROR: -Xdebug is not supported by this script

Tags: solr, solr6

```
 bin/solr start -e techproducts -m 5g -Duser.timezone=US/Eastern -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,suspend=n,transport=dt_socket,address=8000
```

ERROR: -Xdebug is not supported by this script

when i am running solr6.6 on debug mode, its giving me error.
can someone tell me how to run solr on debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact use case is given in the examples in the script:

```
./solr start -c -m 1g -z localhost:2181 -a \"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044\""

-a            Additional parameters to pass to the JVM when starting Solr, such as to setup
              Java debug options. For example, to enable a Java debugger to attach to the Solr JVM
              you could pass: -a \"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=18983\"
              In most cases, you should wrap the additional parameters in double quotes.
```